# AssertJ: Get the path of differences with usingRecursiveComparison()

Tags: java, assertj

It is hard when using usingRecursiveComparison() in AssertJ for some objects tree to figure out where the difference is in case of comparison failure.
With simple objects relations AssertJ returns the path of the difference between objects.
When using collections there are no details of the path where the difference is.

Using usingRecursiveComparison() in AssertJ with following structure:

```
@Test
   public void test() {
      final Level1 first = new Level1( new Level2( new Level3( "first1" ) ) );
      final Level1 second = new Level1( new Level2( new Level3( "second1" ) ) );
      assertThat( first ).usingRecursiveComparison().isEqualTo( second );
   }

   public record Level1(Level2 level2) {
   }

   public record Level2(Level3 level3) {
   }

   public record Level3(String text) {
   }
```

running the test we get the message (which is fine): the error has the path to the difference.

```
field/property 'level2.level3.text' differ:
- actual value  : "first1"
- expected value: "second1"
```

Changing the structure to Sets:

```
   public void test() {
      final Level1 first = new Level1( Set.of( new Level2( Set.of( new Level3( "first1" ), new Level3( "first2" ) ) ) ) );
      final Level1 second = new Level1( Set.of( new Level2( Set.of( new Level3( "second1" ) ) ) ) );
      assertThat( first ).usingRecursiveComparison().isEqualTo( second );
   }

   public record Level1(Set<Level2> level2) {
   }

   public record Level2(Set<Level3> level3) {
   }

   public record Level3(String text) {
   }
```

running the test the message returned:

```
field/property 'level2' differ:
- actual value  : [Level2[level3=[Level3[text=first1], Level3[text=first2]]]]
- expected value: [Level2[level3=[Level3[text=second1]]]]
The following expected elements were not matched in the actual Set12:
  [Level2[level3=[Level3[text=second1]]]]
```

Debugging AssertJ there are some ComparisonDifference objects which might be useful, but these get lost:

```
ComparisonDifference [path=level2.level3, actual=[Level3[text=first1], Level3[text=first2]], expected=[Level3[text=second1]], template=%s differ:%n- actual value  : %s%n- expected value: %s%s,additionalInformation=actual and expected values are collections of different size, actual size=2 when expected size=1]
```

Is it possible to get more insights of the path where the difference actually is?

Answer (score 0):

This possible with ordered collections (list or array) but with Sets it's more complicated, you can only say that an element is missing, that element has been compared with all the elements of the other so you cannot pinpoint a specific element from the other set.

Feel free to raise an issue in assertj with a test case showing the actual error and then tell us which error you would have liked to see

Comment: Hi, but RecursiveComparisonDifferenceCalculator class already returns a good hint: 

ComparisonDifference [path=level2.level3, actual=[Level3[text=first1], Level3[text=first2]], expected=[Level3[text=second1]], template=%s differ:%n- actual value  : %s%n- expected value: %s%s,additionalInformation=actual and expected values are collections of different size, actual size=2 when expected size=1]

So from this it easier to figure out what is going on. But this message is lost up the stack.

Comment: Your example is to simplistic since your sets have only one value, it's the only case where we can actually know which elements exactly did not match.
Try adding more elements and think about what failed comparisons should be reported.